# Arduinoのライブラリを上手くインストールできません。

Tags: arduino

教材に従って「pitches.h」というライブラリをArduino IDEにインストールしようとしています。
　スケッチ　→ ライブラリをインクルード　→ .ZIP形式のライブラリをインストール
でZIP形式のライブラリ（pitches.zip）を選択すると、

```
「pitches」というライブラリはすでに存在します。
```

というエラーが表示されます。そこでスケッチ→ライブラリをインクルードで現れるプルダウンメニューをチェックしても、「pitches」は表示されていません。そのままコンパイルしても「pitches.h: No such file or directory」というエラーを得るので、ライブラリはインストールできていないようです。因みにコンパイルした時に出るエラー・メッセージの全文は以下の通りです。

```
passive_buzzer:4:10: fatal error: pitches.h: No such file or directory
 #include "pitches.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
exit status 1
pitches.h: No such file or directory
```

ソース・コード上で「pitches.h」を""で囲んでも<>で囲んでも結果は同じでした。

「pitches.zip」を解凍すると「pitches」というフォルダが生成され、その中に「pitches.h」というファイルが一つだけ生成されました。試しに「pitches」フォルダを削除して「pitches.h」ファイルのみをZIP形式で圧縮し「.ZIP形式のライブラリをインストール」したところ、「指定されたZIPファイルにはライブラリが含まれていません。」というエラーを得ました。オリジナルのファイルのフォルダ構成の問題ではないようです。

「pitches.zip」はユーザー・フォルダの「Document/Arduino/Libraries/」のフォルダに格納されています。中のファイルに対して特別なアクセス制限をした記憶はありませんが、ファイルを編集しようとするとMac OSがユーザーのパスワードを訊いてきます。従って、
　システム環境設定　→ セキュリティとプライバシー　→ フルディスクアクセス
でArduinoを追加してみましたが、状況は変わりませんでした。

「Document/Arduino/Libraries/」の別なライブラリ・ファイルでも結果は同じでした。

長くなりましたが、Arduino IDEでライブラリを上手くインストールする方法が分かる方、アドバイス宜しくお願い致します。

環境：
Arduino：1.8.13 (Mac OS X), ボード："Arduino Mega or Mega 2560, ATmega2560 (Mega 2560)"

Comment: 『「pitches」というライブラリはすでに存在します』というのですから、インストールされているのだと思われます。

コンパイルするとエラーが出るとの事ですが、そのプログラム（スケッチ）はファイルメニューの「保存」か「名前を付けて保存」かを使ってパソコンに保存したものですか？
コンパイルできるのは、保存されたプログラムだけのはずです。

コンパイルした際に出るエラーの全文を質問に追加すると、より適切な回答が得られると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。スケッチはローカルに保存されたものです。コンパイルした時に出るエラーの全文を質問内に追記しました。

Answer (score 1):

ライブラリをインストールできない原因が分かりました！ライブラリを保存する場所が悪かったようです。以下の手順でライブラリをインストール、及びインクルードできました。

1. ライブラリとスケッチブックの両ファイルを「スケッチブックの保存場所」に保存し、
2. 「スケッチブックの保存場所」のスケッチブックを開く。（自動的にフォルダが生成され、そのフォルダにスケッチブックが移動した後、スケッチブックのウィンドウが開きます。）
3. 開いたウィンドウから「スケッチブックの保存場所」のライブラリをインストールし（ `"スケッチ" → "ライブラリをインクルード" → ".ZIP形式のライブラリをインストール"`）、インクルードする（`"スケッチ" → "ライブラリをインクルード" → プルダウンメニューからライブラリを選択`）。

「スケッチブックの保存場所」はメイン・メニューの`"Arduino" → "Preferences"`で指定できます。この方法はArduinoに添付されている別のスケッチブックとその関連ライブラリに対して有効でした。

お騒がせしました。